# Rabbitmq-server fails to start if hostname has subdomain

Tags: rabbitmq

Not sure if this is expected but here is what I have found on Ubuntu 16.04. I have named everything via apps and instance count. In example for logstash you have 1.logstash.test.com 2.logstash.test.com 3.logstash.test.com. However rabbitmq-server wont start with that, the hostname cannot have a subdomain name.

```
Setting up rabbitmq-server (3.5.7-1) ...
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
```

When changing the hostname to just logstash.test.com, it works just fine for installing via apt-get. Everything is setup properly in /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname.

Answer (score 1):

The following workaround fixed it for me.

On Ubuntu, I added the following to /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf

```
HOSTNAME=rabbitmq
```

Make sure to also add an entry for rabbitmq to your /etc/hosts file, otherwise rabbitmq-server will complain that it’s not resolvable:

```
# Resolve rabbitmq to 127.0.2.2, so we're not interferring with other localhost hostnames
127.0.2.2 rabbitmq
```

After that, starting rabbitmq-server

```
sudo invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start
```